# Why my php form ia not sending email

Tags: php, html, email

I had an email form working before with what I believe is this code. But all of a sudden it's not shooting out anymore emails.

Here's my code.
This is the cod for HTML file, with function. before it was working, but I dont know what happened suddenly it stop working.

Form.html

```
<form method="POST"action="process.php">
NAMN:<br>
<input type="text" size="60" maxlength="60" name="Namn" value=""><br> 
ADRESS:<br> 
<input type="text" size="60" maxlength="60" name="ADRESS" value=""><br> 
POSTADRESS:<br> 
<input type="text" size="60" maxlength="60" name="POSTADRESS" value=""><br>
E-POST:<br> 
<input type="text" size="60" maxlength="60" name="EPOST" value=""><br> 
TELEFON:<br> 
<input type="text" size="60" maxlength="60" name="TELEFON" value=""><br> 
MOBILTELEFON:<br> 
<input type="text" size="60" maxlength="60" name="M_TELEFON" value=""><br> 
PERSONUMMER:<br> 
<input type="text" size="60" maxlength="60" name="PERSONNUMMER" value=""><br>
VÄLJ SVART FÄRG HÄR: <br> 
<input type="text" size="60" maxlength="60" name="FARG" value=""><br>
VÄLJ SVART/RÖD FÄRG:<br> 
<input type="text" size="60" maxlength="60" name="R_FARG" value=""><br>
VÄLJ SVART/BEIGE FÄRG:<br> 
<input type="text" size="60" maxlength="60" name="B_FARG" value=""><br> 
VÄLJ SVART/TURKOS FÄRG:<br> 
<input type="text" size="60" maxlength="60" name="T_FARG" value=""><br> 
VÄLJ ANNAN FÄRG NEDAN 14 arbetsdagars leveranstid:<br> 
<input type="text" size="60" maxlength="60" name="A_FARG" value=""><br> 
     <br>

MEDDELANDE:<br> 
<textarea name="MEDDELANDE" cols="60" rows="6">
</textarea><br> 
<input type="submit" value="SKICKA!" id="btn"> 
<input type="reset" value="RADERA!"> 

</form>
```

process.php

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['Namn'];
$ADRESS = $_POST['ADRESS'];
$POSTADRESS = $_POST['POSTADRESS'];
$EPOST = $_POST['EPOST'];
$TELEFON = $_POST['TELEFON'];
$M_TELEFON = $_POST['M_TELEFON'];
$PERSONNUMMER = $_POST['PERSONNUMMER'];
$FARG = $_POST['FARG'];
$R_FARG = $_POST['R_FARG'];
$B_FARG = $_POST['B_FARG'];
$T_FARG = $_POST['T_FARG'];
$A_FARG = $_POST['A_FARG'];
$MEDDELANDE = $_POST['MEDDELANDE'];

$recipient="zia_gt@yahoo.com";
$subject="Form to $EPOST Order";
$mailBody="NAMN: $name \nADRESS: $ADRESS \nPOSTADRESS: $POSTADRESS \nE-POST: $EPOST \nTELEFON: $TELEFON \n MOBILTELEFON: $M_TELEFON \nPERSONUMMER: $PERSONNUMMER \nVÄLJ SVART FÄRG: $FARG \nVÄLJ SVART/RÖD FÄRG: $R_FARG \nVÄLJ SVART/BEIGE FÄRG: $B_FARG \nVÄLJ SVART/TURKOS FÄRG: $T_FARG \nVÄLJ ANNAN FÄRG NEDAN 14 arbetsdagars leveranstid: $A_FARG \nMEDDELANDE: $MEDDELANDE\n";


mail("zia_gt@yahoo.com", "Subject:Order received from Euro Baby", $mailBody, "From: $EPOST");
?>
<div id="message_response">
<?php $thankYou="Tack $name! Din beställning har skickats. Vi återkommer till dig inom 24 timmar.";?>
<h1 style="color:#ffffff;">
<?php echo "$thankYou"; ?>
</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: anytime the mail function stops working properly it has to do with the host. you might be missing a package or something that was installed or has gotten corrupt and it stops making the mail function work. do you see any errors when you send mail?

Comment: well, we need more information about the problem, but it seems like an error of the server.

Comment: It is showing no error, and I am using it on live server

Comment: Wish we could help you.. But there is not enough information here..

Comment: Yaco, what more information you needed. http://eurobaby.info/web_shop_error.html

Comment: If simple php mail function is not working try to use https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer with SMTP option..!

Comment: Hello Umair Shah rora, I can not use it... chal na razi

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail. There's multiple factors to this problem.

Comment: it still not working, i tried much stuff

Comment: I used the if statement, and it show the message sending fail.. so the email is not working